# Continuity of a function?

Tags: general-topology, metric-spaces

> Let $f: (\mathbb N, e_\mathbb N) \to(\mathbb R,e)$, where $e$ stands for the euclidean metric and
>   $$f(n)=\begin{cases} n,\, n\ge 2\\\\0,\, n=1\end{cases}$$
>     Is $f$ continuous?

Firstly, I can prove that $d_0,\,  e_\mathbb N$ are topologically equivalent in $\mathbb N$, which means that every $A\subset \mathbb N$ is $d_0-$ open and $e_\mathbb N-$ open.

Secondly, we consider an open set $B \in (\mathbb R,e)$.

If $f$ is continuous, then $f^{-1}(B)$ must be open in  ($\mathbb N, e_\mathbb N$).

However,  $f^{-1}(B)= \{ x \in \mathbb N: f(x) \in B\}\subset \mathbb N$, which means $f^{-1}(B)$ is open in $(\mathbb N, e_\mathbb N)$. Thus, we have that $f$ is continuous.

Is it right?

**Edited**

Comment: Every functions between (topological) spaces whose domain is discrete is continuous.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint:** A function is continuous if the inverse image of any open set is open.

Consider which subsets of $\mathbb{N}$ are open.